# C# dynamically add setting to settings file and saving the setting

Tags: c#

I'm currently using the below code to add a setting to my settings file, but it's not saving the setting. How can I fix this issue? Thanks in advance.

```
System.Configuration.SettingsProperty property = new System.Configuration.SettingsProperty("CustomSetting");
property.DefaultValue = "Default";
property.IsReadOnly = false;
property.PropertyType = typeof(string);
property.Provider = Properties.Settings.Default.Providers["LocalFileSettingsProvider"];
property.Attributes.Add(typeof(System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute), new System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute());
Properties.Settings.Default.Properties.Add(property);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to save added properties

```
Properties.Settings.Default.Properties.Save();
Properties.Settings.Default.Properties.Reload();
```

Comment: Do you have to add the property every time you restart your program ?

Comment: @IanVos what do you mean? This comment to the asnwer or to the question?

Comment: This is a comment to the answer. When you save the properties you cant access them the next time you start your program.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context